# How do I save a cookie in wordpress function php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to save the user id in a cookie after registering them in a wordpress function: however, the function below doesnt save the cookie. anything i'm missing here?

```
function register_user_form() {
    $user_login = $_POST['currentUserName'];
    $user_email = $_POST['currentUserEmail'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['currentUserPassword'];
    $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass' );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

    $cookie_name = "userid";
    $cookie_value = $user_id;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
```

Comment: Did you test the `setcookie()` with just a string?

Comment: @Flexy, yep, tried with a string, but still didnt save the cookie - shouldnt be an issue running on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are strings. The return value of `wp_insert_user()` is an integer. You need to convert that to a string first before trying to set the cookie or it could fail. Try:

```
function register_user_form() {
    $user_login = $_POST['currentUserName'];
    $user_email = $_POST['currentUserEmail'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['currentUserPassword'];
    $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass' );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

    $cookie_name = "userid";
    $cookie_value = strval($user_id); // Convert to a string
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
```

Comment: thanks @DubVader i tried it as a string, but still no joy

Comment: When you send the Ajax request on the frontend, does Wordpress successfully receive and make the callback? You could also try setting a variable for the setcookie() function and echo the return value. It's not foolproof but you could see if the setcookie() is the problem or not.